# Senda Data in Socket C#, format EBCDIC

Tags: c#, sockets, ebcdic

I have to send a data in EBCDIC, the data original is:

"180420300180000000000000001234561708291730008318700"

The data string in EBCDIC (Excepts 2030018000000000000000):

"F1F8F0F42030018000000000F0F0F0F0F0F0F1F2F3F4F5F6F1F7F0F8F2F9F1F7F3F0F0F0F8F3F1F8F7F0F0"

I send this info with a socket, but the people in the other point said me to the info arrived like ascii:

"4631463846304630...." = "F1F8F0F0... "

I need send this info like EBCDIC, this people said me that, someone understand this issue? Maybe the Encoding before send the string:

byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message); //Implements EBCDIC

Regards

Comment: http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/ebcdic/

Comment: Don't work this solution, regards

Comment: Question solved in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46226396/iso8583-for-amex